# VSCode Terminal: The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: node.js, windows, visual-studio-code, cmd

The problem is that I can actually access the C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe through Windows CMD like : node -v:

```
C:\Users\User>node -v
v16.13.0
```

But the Visual Studio Code (with installed node.js extension pack) doesn't recognize the node in terminal. All that I could have found myself is that:

1. I should include the nodejs folder in my PATH variable (done already) and
2. restart my PC
3. restart IDE.

- All of the three steps were done but still VSCode doesn't recognize the "node" command in terminal.

```
node : The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
```

Answer (score 5):

Everything is working for now, I just had to manually close and re-open terminal through VSCode -> Terminal -> New Terminal, also pressing the "Powershell" button on terminal panel could've solved the issue.

Comment: If this does not work try restarting VSCode.